# Show post result with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to make a simple sending form with jquery. this is my code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".someButton").click(function(){
     var response = $('#dle-poke').val()
     var responses = $('#dle-pokes').val()
     $.post(dle_root + 'engine/ajax/fastpm.php', {text:response, texts:responses, action:"fastqpro"},

  function(data) {      
  });   

});
});
```

**PHP:**

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "fastqpro") {
  $title= $db->safesql($text);
  $db->query("INSERT INTO dle_post (`autor`, `title`) values ('{$name}', '{$title}')");
}
```

Everything is working, but i need to show send result.

for example if title is empty or something like this:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "fastqpro") {
  if($text == "" ){
    "Title is empty"
  };
  $title= $db->safesql($text);
  $db->query("INSERT INTO dle_post (`autor`, `title`) values ('{$name}', '{$title}')");
}
```

And, if everything was ok, i need to show the OK message and hidding the form.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="area">
  <input id='dle-pokes' type='text' /><br>
  <textarea name='dle-poke' id='dle-poke'></textarea>
  <div id='resault'></div>
</div>
```

How i can get and show the result from my php code and showing in the html page?

Comment: Just a humble advice: please indent your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss `echo` in your PHP code.

it should be

```
if($text == "" ){
    echo "Title is empty";
};
```

To show result in your `div` add this to `function(data)`:

```
$('#resault').html(data);
```

Your div id has a typo but i guess it doesn't matter here, just pay attention that div id and selector in jquery are the same :)

Generally it should be:

jQuery:

```
$.post('mywebsite.com/adress.php', {variable1_name: var1_value, variable2: value2}, function(data) {
    $('element_selector').html(data);
});
```

PHP:

```
$var1 = $_POST['variable1_name'];
$var2 = $_POST['variable2'];

//..... do something

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way :

```
 if ($_POST['action'] == "fastqpro") {
  if($text == "" ){
    echo "Title is empty";
  }else{
  $title= $db->safesql($text);
  $db->query("INSERT INTO dle_post (`autor`, `title`) values ('{$name}', '{$title}')");
  echo "Success Message";
  }
}
```

After that in jquery script area put after  `function(data){`

```
$('#resault').html(data);
```

Comment: sorry, there is no way to accept all answers :D but thank u very much